# How can we set path attribute for cookies in web.config file for .net web application

Tags: asp.net, web-config, session-cookies, websecurity, cookie-path

I need to set cookies path to my application directory so that cookies should not be shared across other domain/sub domain.

How can i set cookies path in the web.config file?

At present i have below configuration-

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requiredSSL="true" />
```

Now how can i add path so that cookies are not shared with other application.
I can see -

```
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionID= XXXX; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

Path=/ - is presently defaulted to root level which I need to explicitly defined to application level and that too in the web.config file

My site url would be like -
Www.WebApp.Company.com/VirtualDirectory/Page.aspx

Now i wanted to restrict cookies to be accessible within VirtualDirectory and not with other applications added in web server.

Any web security expert please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it should be :
Set-Cookie: Secure; HttpOnly; path=/WebApp.Company.com/VirtualDirectory;